# How to fix ‘TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable’ error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation

I'm doing the FDTD (Finite Differences in Time Domain) method, and I set a 'Hterm' variable to receive an expression within a while, and this generates this error, and the rest of the code is right without any other error

already tried to define its type previously, to replace the expression to see if this was the error but until now nothing

These are the variables I use for the expression

```
Hz = Hz*PEC
c_eps = float(del_t / eps / del_s)
```

This is just the beginning of the loop where error happens

```
while (done != 0):

    Ex_o = Ex
    Ey_o = Ey
    Hz_o = Hz

Hterm = c_eps*(Hz(range[2:(nodes1 - 1)], range[1:nodes1]) - Hz(range[1:nodes1 - 2], range[1:nodes1]))
```

I expect the output to be low values close to 0 and q to be plotted in the graph and being updated during the loop

Comment: What is `range`? And can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Unless you over-wrote the built-in `range` with a list, you are basically trying to slice the type object `range` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range. If you are trying to generate a range of values it would be `list(range(2,(nodes1 - 1)))` or `[*range(2,(nodes1 - 1))]`.